# unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Tags: java

There's two classes:
The main one (`Corina.java`) and the one that I am having issues with (`Functions.java`). Without complicating things too much, `Corina.java` calls a method in `Functions.java`, the method checks if a `boolean` is `true` or `false` and asks for authentication based on that, the code is very impartial at the moment, though I am using a phidgets RFID reader and copied a portion of one of their examples. but I get the following error in JCreator:

```
--------------------Configuration: Corina - JDK version 1.7.0_45 <Default> - <Default>--------------------
C:\Users\alexis.JKLSEMICOLON\Documents\JCreator LE\MyProjects\Corina\src\Functions.java:23: error: unreported exception Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown
            authenticateContinue();

                            ^
```

First class code:

```
public class Corina {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Functions funtion = new Functions();
        funtion.authenticateStart();
    }
}
```

Second class code:

```
import com.phidgets.*;
import com.phidgets.event.*;

public class Functions {

    public void authenticateStart() {
        boolean authStatus = false;
        System.out.println("The authentication status is currently: " + authStatus + ".");
        if (authStatus) {
            System.out.println("The applications is unlocked. Please wait.");
            //  applicationStart();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please authenticate now by swiping one of the RFID tags allowed to unlock the program.");
            authenticateContinue();
        }

    }

    public void authenticateContinue() throws Exception {
        RFIDPhidget rfid;

        System.out.println(Phidget.getLibraryVersion());

        rfid = new RFIDPhidget();
        rfid.addAttachListener(new AttachListener() {
            public void attached(AttachEvent ae) {
                try {

                    ((RFIDPhidget) ae.getSource()).setAntennaOn(true);

                    ((RFIDPhidget) ae.getSource()).setLEDOn(true);
                } catch (PhidgetException ex) {
                }
                System.out.println("attachment of " + ae);
            }
        });
        rfid.addDetachListener(new DetachListener() {
            public void detached(DetachEvent ae) {
                System.out.println("detachment of " + ae);
            }
        });
        rfid.addErrorListener(new ErrorListener() {
            public void error(ErrorEvent ee) {
                System.out.println("error event for " + ee);
            }
        });
        rfid.addTagGainListener(new TagGainListener() {
            public void tagGained(TagGainEvent oe) {
                System.out.println(oe);
            }
        });
        rfid.addTagLossListener(new TagLossListener() {
            public void tagLost(TagLossEvent oe) {
                System.out.println(oe);
            }
        });
        rfid.addOutputChangeListener(new OutputChangeListener() {
            public void outputChanged(OutputChangeEvent oe) {
                System.out.println(oe);
            }
        });

        rfid.openAny();
        System.out.println("waiting for RFID attachment...");
        rfid.waitForAttachment(1000);

        System.out.println("Serial: " + rfid.getSerialNumber());
        System.out.println("Outputs: " + rfid.getOutputCount());

        System.out.println("Outputting events. Input to stop.");
        System.in.read();
        System.out.print("closing...");
        rfid.close();
        rfid = null;
        System.out.println(" ok");
        if (false) {
            System.out.println("wait for finalization...");
            System.gc();
        }
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated. Ideally, I would like to just have the tag saved to a string, so if you would be knowledgeable on that, by all means.

Comment: It would help readability a lot if you would indent your code correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that `authenticateStart` calls `authenticateContinue()`, but you've flagged `authenticateContinue` as able to throw an `Exception`.  That means that `authenticateStart` needs to be able to deal with that exception when it's thrown.  You have a couple of options.

1. Put the call to `authenticateContinue` inside a `try` block, and deal with the exception in a `catch` block beneath it.
2. Change `authenticateContinue` so that it doesn't throw a checked exception.
3. Flag `authenticateStart` as able to throw an `Exception`.  This will push the problem up into `main`, where you're calling `authenticateStart`.

No matter what you do, you'll have to deal with that exception somehow.  The whole point of Java exception handling is that you can't just leave checked exceptions unhandled - you have to deal with them somehow.